# Minifying only JS files in webpack build

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs, webpack-style-loader

I'm using webpack for my production build, as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/index'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en|he/),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'test')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?-minimize!sass!postcss-loader'),
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loader: 'url?limit=8192',
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'assets')
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'babel!svg-react',
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'assets')
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })]
};
```

As you can see, the code is minified by `UglifyJsPlugin`. The problem is that it also minifies the CSS files (which are extracted by `ExtractTextPlugin`). I want to avoid the CSS minification in order to process it after the build.

How can I tell the plugin to minify only my JS file?

Thanks,
*Tomer*

Comment: I tried to split the build into chunks, and exclude the CSS chunk from the `UglifyJsPlugin`, but with no success.

Answer (score -1):

See: [Webpack Uglify errors in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294628)
You can add a `test` to uglify and filter files by a regex...

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/
})
```

Or...

You don't have to do everything in one `webpack.config.js`.

Since you're building the css to a separate file, have two webpack.configs, one to do the js and another to do the css.  Don't forget to build both.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your first solution won't work. `UglifyJsPlugin` gets the code already bundled to `bundle.js` so filtering regexp is useless. As for the second one, it can work I guess, but it involves too many changes in the build process which I would like to prevent.